# Access blogs in computer lab without using the ip address?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, ip-address

I'm a teacher, our school has a computer lab.
Currently using Xampp and Wordpress to have kids blog.  I keep a website with with links to all the kids blogs so that they can read each others blogs.  It's all behind the districts fire wall so it's not accessible to anyone accept those on our LAN.
Question I have is this...The IP address change sometimes.  This requires me to go figure out what the new IP address is on all 30 computers in the lab and to change all of the links so the kids can read each others blogs.  Is there a way to type something else in the url bar in order to get to a computer blog. I'm wonding if I can do like http://computername/index  and have it find that computers blog without needing an ip lookup?
I use remote desktop to control these computer with just the host name...will something like this work for browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to browse to other computers in your local network by visiting http://computername/index, however there are some potential caveats to that depending on the architecture of the local network that you're using.

There is a better way, though. Rather than maintaining 30 separate XAMPP and Wordpress installs, why not designate one PC in the lab as the server, and set this up to run one instance of XAMPP and one instance of [Wordpress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)?

This way, a nearly unlimited number of students can manage and browse their own blogs in a central repository, and you only have to maintain your software on a single machine. There are [plugins which list all your sites](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-site-site-list-shortcode/), so you won't have to keep this list updated manually.

It also gives you the ability to further restrict your students' admin dashboards to keep them from getting distracted while twiddling with Wordpress' knobs and dials.

Finally, since everyone's blogs reside on the same machine, you will eventually have someone's password get compromised and one student's blog will be "hacked" by another, so you'll get the teachable moment of strong, secure passwords.